« En haut » ou « au-dessus » en ce contexte
Je ne suis pas sûre s'il y a une différence d'usage entre en haut et au-dessus dans le contexte suivant.
Puis-je dire

J'habite au 2ème étage et Isabelle a acheté un appartement à l'étage au-dessus, au 3ème

avec le même sens que

J'habite au 2ème étage et Isabelle a acheté un appartement à l'étage en haut, au 3ème ?

Dans le Trésor de la Langue Française, j'ai trouvé

Loc. adv. Au(-)dessus. Plus haut. Au-dessus, le pic dressait son grand cône baigné de soleil (LOTI, Mon frère Yves, 1883, p. 176)

et

En haut, loc. adv. 
a) Dans la partie haute, la plus haute (avec et sans mouvement). Aller, pousser, tirer en haut; depuis le bas jusqu'en haut; boutonné jusqu'en haut. Ma fenêtre, percée en haut, était munie de bons barreaux de fer qui me laissaient voir quelques toits gothiques (CHATEAUBR., Mém., t. 4, 1848, p. 720). Une fois arrivés en haut, nous descendions en voiture, revenions par le même chemin (PROUST, Sodome, 1922, p. 1004).

Selon ces informations, il me semble que oui, mais je n'en suis pas tout à fait sûre.
J'ai lu les réponses à cette question, mais elles ne clarifient pas mon doute. Il me semble qu'il est difficile de donner une explication générale complète sur les différences entre ces expressions, c'est pourquoi j'ai préféré me limiter à un contexte concret.

Les réponses données en référence couvre exactement ton cas. La position que tu veux donner est relative (puisqu'il ya une comparaison avec le 3e étage) donc c'est au-dessus qui est correct. On emploierait en haut pour dire par exemple J'habite au 2e étage et Isabelle a acheté un appartement en haut du même immeuble (ce qui ne veut pas dire qu'il est juste au-dessus).

This question is similar to: Différence entre « en haut / en bas » et « au-dessus / au-dessous ». If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Il y a une différence grammaticale, expliquée par Frank dans sa réponse: au-dessus est comparatif, en haut est locatif.

Pas tout à fait la même chose. Dans le premier exemple, en haut semble moins spécifique, et en particulier, ne fait pas partie d'une comparaison avec le 2ème étage, alors que au dessus indique clairement que les deux étages sont comparés. En haut signifie "quelque part vers le haut de la maison", alors qu'au dessus est utilisé pour comparer spécifiquement le 2ème et le 3ème étages.
On a sans doute l'habitude d'utiliser au dessus (de) pour la comparaison, mais pas en haut (de). Par exemple:

Cette photo est en haut de la bibliothèque.


Cette photo est au dessus de la bibliothèque.

Dans la première phrase, la photo est quelque part vers le haut de la bibliothèque, dans la bibliothèque, il s'agit du haut de la bibliothèque, ses dernières étagères. Dans la deuxième phrase, la photo est clairement plus haut que la bibliothèque, probablement sur le mur au dessus de la bibliothèque, et on a fait une comparaison des positions des deux objets.
Il est possible qu'on utilise maintenant "en haut de" de façon complètement interchangeable avec "au dessus de", mais cet usage ne m'est pas familier.

La première phrase est de registre familier :

J'habite au 2ème étage et Isabelle a acheté un appartement à l'étage au-dessus, au 3ème.

On dira plus souvent à l'étage du dessus qui aussi précise clairement de quel étage il s'agit.
On peut aussi dire à l'étage juste au-dessus qui met l'emphase sur la proximité des deux appartements. Dans les deux cas, ajouter au 3ème ajoute une information redondante mais quand même utile.
La deuxième phrase est maladroite et peu idiomatique :

J'habite au 2ème étage et Isabelle a acheté un appartement à l'étage en haut, au 3ème.

Sans la précision au 3ème, on ne saurait pas vraiment où se trouve précisément cet étage et si on disait à l'étage du haut, ce ne serait pas mieux car ça signifierait le dernier étage donc pas forcément celui situé immédiatement au dessus du 2ème.
